# Spring security JWT Authentication on POST request with large file / slow internet connection

Tags: spring-security, jwt

Im facing a situation where I dont have a solution for.

I have the following setup:

- Web Application calling a POST method on my Spring backend.
- Backend is secured by JWT Authentication
- Backend is a classic MVC Application

The *BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter* is called after the bytes are received and the Filterchain is processed.

Assume that the Request takes longer than the expiration time, the JWT processing is giving me a "token expired" and the request is rejected.

Has anybody faced the same situation than me and found a way to solve it ?

Is there a way to get bearer token check before the actual byte stream is received ?

I thought about using a reative API, but before doing this fundamental change I thought I call out for help.

Thanks,
detlef

Additional Information:

- Within my App a user can upload files. This upload is restricted to users having a valid jwt token containing a certain role.
- Uploading a file does a POST with a header parameter '*Authorization: Bearer ey......*'
- My RestController method handling the uploaded file is called after the MultipartFile is completely uploaded.
- The time between the client starts the upload and the file is received from the RestController is longer that the validity of the JWT token.
- So the authorization is rejected with a 401 error.

Hope this helps to clarify the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

after digging down into various classes, I found out what causes this behaviour. The key here is that when sending multipart content to the server, the whole data is received before further filters come into action.

Replacing the multipart upload, the Filters are applied first and the content can then be read after Authentication is completed.

Maybe this helps others too.